# Openlayers 4 shows only 1/4 of SVG image

Tags: svg, openlayers

I'm trying to mark a coordinates with SVG icon in Openlayers 4.3.3:

```
import ControllerRecordIcon from '../icons/entypo/controller-record.svg';

vector.setStyle(new Style({
  image: new IconStyle({
    scale: 0.5,
    src: ControllerRecordIcon
  })
}));

map.addLayer(vector);
```

Icon is from [Entypo](http://www.entypo.com/) package and this is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Record" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M10,3c-3.866,0-7,3.133-7,7c0,3.865,3.134,7,7,7s7-3.135,7-7C17,6.133,13.866,3,10,3z"/>
</svg>
```

You can see the problem in the attached image. There is only top left quarter of icon visible and it's not centered on coordinates (red dot marks the coordinates). Scaling doesn't help, icon gets smaller but still shows only 1/4 of image and is not centered.

I tried multiple params from [Icon API](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.Icon.html), but they either make no difference or icon disappears completely.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Record" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width='20'  height='20' xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M10,3c-3.866,0-7,3.133-7,7c0,3.865,3.134,7,7,7s7-3.135,7-7C17,6.133,13.866,3,10,3z"/>
</svg>
```

use this one

Comment: Thanks, Chandu! Now I can see the icon properly. Another problem emerges - it doesn't stay on coordinates now, instead moves with the zoom: [video attached](https://monosnap.com/file/mi8Xs1jFzSxTh3RfWUGsRjsIa4p4Jr)
Is this because of bad config of Openlayers Feature/Icon or something else?

Comment: OK, I fixed it - entypo icons are 20x20px, changing your code to `width='20' height='20'` did the trick